# Error displaying localhost:8000/phpmyadmin in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, localhost

When I start laravel using 'php artisan serve' it directs me to localhost:8000(and it works). But when I use localhost:8000/phpmyadmin to open phpmyadmin it throws an error.

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

```
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('/var/www/html/cms/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

I have tried changing the port number using 'php artisan serve --port 8888'.
I am using xampp server. Please help!

Comment: You need to access phpmyadmin through xampp's http server, it won't work through artisan serve.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access phpmyadmin, you must access it through XAMPP server in link `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php`

And `php artisan serve` make a serveri port `localhost:8000` for only laravel app. 
You must know this is two different type between laravel and your XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

You can just try with the following simple two steps in config.

1. httpd.conf

[image]

2. Enable the rewrite_module and allow none in the 2) line

   1) Just remove # in this line #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

   2) Replace 'AllowOverride None' by 'AllowOverride All'

And also You can specify with the following simple way in artisan server.

```
php artisan serve --port=8888
```

Answer (score 0):

You always can access your phpmyadmin without port,
and make sure you type it in lowercase.

Answer (score -1):

You can put phpmyadmin folder inside public and access it via http://127.0.0.1:8000/phpmyadmin/index.php

However, why don't you host it on xampp and config the port via vhost file?

Comment: I had put phpmyadmin folder inside public. But now I am getting an error saying: MySQL said: Documentation
Cannot connect: invalid settings.
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

Comment: well, I recomend you xampp instead, but ill think about another solution

Comment: I also configured the host to port=8000 and used the url localhost:8000/phpmyadmin.The phpmyadmin page is displayed. However, when I use the 'php artisan serve', it says '[Sun Jan 20 23:43:22 2019] Failed to listen on localhost:8000 (reason: Address already in use)'.

Comment: You can host it via php artisan serve or via xampp not both :)